# box is adding new files instead of updating my file. Why? How to make it stop?

Tags: box.com

My company started me on "box" about two weeks ago.  It has been OK.  But as of this afternoon, one of the main files I work with is not being updated.  I have it stored in box.  I open it from there.  I work on it.  But when I save it, box creates a new file instead of updating the original.  I now have several files with names like `"my file (my.email@my.company 5) .docx"`  Why is this happening?  How do I get the standard behavior back? FWIW, I am working from a Windows 10 machine.

Comment: Make a backup of the version you want, preferably in some other location. Delete the file and its copies. Wait 5 minutes. Replace the file. Does that fix it?

Comment: @Mokubai  That seemed to do it.  Thanks!  Do you know what was going on?

Comment: Most often it's because you made a change at the same time as someone else had the file locked or made their own edit and it causes a conflict. The software then goes "I ain't dealing with this" until you manually solve it by nuking the file and starting over.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This kind of error in cloud storage tools is most often caused by two people editing or locking the file at the same time which causes a conflict as the server has no idea which version of the file is more important.

Generally the most generic way to "reset" it is to

1. Make a backup of the file, preferably by copying it outside of your cloud storage
2. Delete the file in your cloud storage location
3. Wait a few minutes for the changes to synchronise
4. Copy your backup back over into the cloud storage location.

The specific behaviour depends entirely on the program doing the synchronisation.

Box has some specific help at

- [Duplicate Files With Email Address Added After Sync](https://support.box.com/hc/en-us/articles/360044193953-Duplicate-Files-With-Email-Address-Added-After-Sync)
- [File Version Conflicts](https://support.box.com/hc/en-us/articles/360044193873-File-Version-Conflicts)

But it amount (currently) to the fact that Box does not handle conflicts and instead creates these duplicate files and expects the user to handle the merging and managing of conflicts.